# How to filter Array of Map with multiple value using Guava

Tags: java, android, guava, android-guava

I have an Array containing Map. And I want to filter my array using some (multiple) key and value inside of the map object. For example, WHERE ID > 1 AND Name <> "cc"     (key > 1, Name<>"cc").

How can i do that in Java? 
I have imported the Guava libraries that has Collections2 to filter the array. 
But, I didn't found any example that is filtering Map object inside the array.

here is some of my example codes:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> baseList = new ArrayList<>();

            Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
            map1.put("ID", 1);
            map1.put("Name", "aa");
            baseList.add(map1);

            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
            map2.put("ID", 2);
            map2.put("Name", "bb");
            baseList.add(map2);

            Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
            map3.put("ID", 3);
            map3.put("Name", "cc");
            baseList.add(map3);

            List<Map<String, Object>> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            filteredList = Collections2.filter() ???
```

I want to filter with a kind of `ID >= 1 AND NAME<>"cc"` Which will resulting Array containing Map object like this: `[{ID=1,Name="aa"}, {ID=2,Name="bb"}]`

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Java 8? You can do:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> filteredList = maps.stream()
    .filter(map -> (Integer) map.get("ID") >= 1 && !"cc".equals(map.get("Name")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to have new list with filtered maps.

If you want collection *view* using Guava goodies (or no Java 8), you should use [`Collections2.filter`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter-java.util.Collection-com.google.common.base.Predicate-):

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> filteredList = Collections2.filter(
    maps, new Predicate<Map<String, Object>>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(@Nullable Map<String, Object> map) {
        return (Integer) map.get("ID") >= 1 && !"cc".equals(map.get("Name"));
      }
    });
```

there's no `Lists.filter`, see [IdeaGraveyard for explanation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#listsfilter), hence only `Collection` interface is provided.

Do you really need list of maps instead of `Map<Integer, String>` (or maybe `Map<Integer, YourDomainObject>`)? Then you could do:

```
final Map<Integer, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    1, "aa",
    2, "bb",
    3, "cc");
final Map<Integer, String> filteredMap = Maps.filterEntries(map,
    e -> e.getKey() >= 1 && !"cc".equals(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Your explanation on Collections2.filter() explained well to me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what do you need Guava for. I'd do that in the following way:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> filteredList = baseList.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                  .anyMatch(e -> e.getKey().equals(1L) && e.getValue().equals("cc")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I know about Java 8 lambda filtering, but that's not the one I need. But, thanks for your help.